# How do you set a div's location to be centered when we don't know the screen size?

Tags: html, css

I want to set the position of a div at the center of the page without using JavaScript; using only CSS.
The div is a form with a background picture.
How should I do it when I can't use javascript to get screen size?

```
        div.login {
            position: absolute;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            background-image: url("Images/01.jpg");
            width: 500px;
            height: 270px;
        }
```

Comment: This question was answered at least 10 times on SO…

Comment: I read some of them answer,but they don't work.
always I will search and if I can't find I will ask my stackoverflows friend

Comment: "but they don't work" What didn't work? `.login { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }`

Comment: I assume he is looking for something more cross-browser. (IE kills me.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should give you all you need: http://www.wpdfd.com/editorial/thebox/deadcentre3.html

```
<div id="horizon" style="background-color: transparent; text-align: center; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 1px; overflow: visible; visibility: visible; display: block">
    <div id="content" style="background-color: red; margin-left: -125px; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: 50%; width: 250px; height: 20px; visibility: visible">
        <span style="color: white;">This box stays in the absolute center.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above code is a stripped down version of the linked example. It creates a `<div>` that is **always** in the exact center of the page. (Both vertically and horizontally.)

It's a simple and clean method for elements who's dimensions are known, as your question seems to be referring to.

Comment: This is one of my favorite methods and obviously suitable to the OP.  However, since not mentioned, one should note that this only works when the size of the element is known.

Comment: That's true, however in the example code shown by the OP, the width and height were explicitly declared with literal values, therefore I assumed this is applicable to the OP's case. Good point, nonetheless.